# What is the point of making all storage explicitly bounded?

Tags: runtime, pov

There has been a long time goal to move all storage to bounded forms in runtime. I can see that having bounded size limits of all the storage items can be useful to give some guarantees for storage related operations. I am curious what are the specifics of the motivation behind this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For standalone chains making the storage bounded isn't that important. However, for Parachains it is really important. When building a PoV, you always need to take the PoV size into account to not run over the allowed maximum. By making the storage items bounded, you can estimate the worst case size of the PoV after applying a transaction. So, you can reject a transaction early that wouldn't fit anymore into the current block.

Comment: A quick follow up what exactly is included in a POV, I can't quite find that in the codebase

Comment: The final block + the storage proof (aka everything you read from the storage + intermediate trie nodes).